# Find Pair Of Integers in Array whose Sum is Given Number in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

My solution is :

```
function printPairs($array, $sum) { 
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
        $first = $array[$i]; 
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($array); $j++) {
          $second = $array[$j]; 
          if (($first + $second) == $sum) { 
            echo($first.','.$second); 
          } 
       } 
    } 
}
```

complexity of this solution is O(n^2)
How can we improve this, what can we do better to improve this in PHP.

Comment: I was asked in the interview this question, and this was my solution. But I was asked to improve it using PHP. Please help to understand what extra i can do in PHP to make it better.

Comment: I know in java we can use Hash map and make it better, but what can be done in PHP, please help.

Comment: why can't you use hashmaps in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this one question won't make you better at solving problems, you need to truly understand algorithms and their complexity. You can check out https://codility.com/programmers/ if you want to gain more experience in solving problems. There's many answers published for the various lessons, but I'd highly recommend you try to solve them yourself to the best of your ability before you go out seeking answers to the lessons/challenges.

So for this question you were given an array of integers and an integer that you needed to find the pairs.

You were probably also required to ensure that each number (index in array) was only used once.

So if you're input was `[3,7,3]` your pairs would just be `[[3,7]]` and not `[[3,7],[7,3]]`

> Optimized solution

This solution would be considered `O(2n)` or just simplified to `O(n)` as it follows linear time.

```
function solution(array $arr, $int) {
    $results = [];
    $map = [];

    # create a map of ints and how many you have
    $size = sizeof($arr);
    for($x = 0; $x < $size; $x++) {
        $n = $arr[$x];
        if (!array_key_exists($n, $map)) {
            $map[$n] = 0;
        }
        $map[$n]++;
    }

    # loop through and find the pairs
    $size = sizeof($map);
    foreach($map as $n => $c) {
        $w = $int - $n;
        if (!array_key_exists($w, $map)) {
            continue;
        }
        $map[$n]--;
        $map[$w]--;
        # edge case when $n === $w
        if ($map[$n] < 0 || $map[$w] < 0) {
            $map[$n]++;
            $map[$w]++;
            continue;
        }

        $results[] = [$n,$w];
    }

    return $results;
}

echo json_encode(solution([], 10)) . PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode(solution([1], 10)) . PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode(solution([10], 10)) . PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode(solution([0,10], 10)) . PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode(solution([5,5], 10)) . PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode(solution([-5,15], 10)) . PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode(solution([3,7,3], 10)) . PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode(solution([3,7,3,7,1,9], 10)) . PHP_EOL;
```

> output

```
[]
[]
[]
[[0,10]]
[[5,5]]
[[-5,15]]
[[3,7]]
[[3,7],[7,3],[1,9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite your function like this:

```
function printPairs($array, $sum) { 
    $map = [];
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        if (isset($map[$sum-$v])) {
            echo $v . ',' . ($sum-$v) . "\n";
            echo ($sum-$v) . ',' . $v . "\n";
        }
        $map[$v] = 1;
    }
}
```

and average complexity will be O(N)

Comment: @Anant code does not remove anything from the array

Comment: ya, sorry about that, I did deleted my comment. Thanks for your help.